# How to display an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int input = 0;
int binaryNumber = 0;
int decimalNumber = 0;
int remainder = 0;
int i = 1;
int wholeNumber = 0;\
int number = 0;
char hexLetters[] = "ABCDEF";


printf("Press 1 to convert Binary to Hex\n");
printf("Press 2 to convert Hex to Binary\n");
printf("Press 3 to convert Decimal to 2's to Compliment Binary\n");
scanf("%d",&input);
printf("\n");

switch (input)
{
    case 1:
    {

    printf("Enter a Binary number\n");
    scanf("%d",&binaryNumber);

    char binaryToHex[2];
    while(binaryNumber != 0)
    {
        remainder = binaryNumber%10;
        decimalNumber = decimalNumber + (remainder*i);
        i = i*2;
        binaryNumber = binaryNumber/10;
    }
    while(decimalNumber != 0)
    {
    remainder = decimalNumber%16;
    wholeNumber = (decimalNumber%16)-(remainder/16);

    decimalNumber = 0;
    }

    int j = 1;
    for(j=1;j<16;j++){
        if(remainder ==j){
            binaryToHex[1] = hexLetters[j-10];
        }
        else{
            binaryToHex[1] = remainder;
        }
    }

    int k = 1;
    for(k=1;k<16;k++){
        if(wholeNumber == k){
            binaryToHex[0] = hexLetters[k-10];
        }
        else{
            binaryToHex[0] = wholeNumber;
        }
    }

    printf("%c%c\n", binaryToHex[0], binaryToHex[1]);
```

Please help nothing will display, after some tinkering only F will display which is
wrong. I have checked to make sure the remainder and the wholeNumber are working and it does get the correct number however when i try to store a letter to binaryToHex it is always F or its nothing at all. PLEASE HELP

Comment: I suggest using a debugger to step through your code one line at a time to check if it behaves as you expect. Debugging your own code is a very critical skill for any programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem is probably on this line:

```
binaryToHex[1] = remainder;
```

And simiar for the `binaryToHex[0]` statement. This should be a character (and is when it's A-F). Instead, here, you are assigning a number. This will cause the ASCII character corresponding to that number to be printed, which for 0-9, is in the range of unprintable values (NUL-TAB).

The ASCII integers start at 48 for '0'. Therefore, one fix is to add 48, (or to remove all "magic numbers", '0') to the `remainder` and `wholeNumber` variables when forming your final output, e.g.

```
binaryToHex[1] = remainder + '0';
```

The other problem (that I've just realised) are your loops.

```
for(k=1;k<16;k++){
    if(wholeNumber == k){
        binaryToHex[0] = hexLetters[k-10];
    }
    else{
        binaryToHex[0] = wholeNumber;
    }
}
```

So, have a quick think about this. For 1-16, if the number matches, then assign it a hex letter, otherwise, assign the number. This is logically wrong. Say we have the value of 5, `k` will increase until 5, which will then cause the first clause to succeed. This will assign `hexLetters[5-10]` to be assigned to `binaryToHex[0]`, which could actually cause an access violation. Then, `k` will continue to increase to 16, which will cause the `else` clause to carry on being executed, overwriting the value we just got.

To fix, `break` when you have found the correct number, and shuffle your logic a little, for example:

```
for(k=1;k<16;k++){
    if(wholeNumber == k){
        if(k < 10)
            binaryToHex[0] = k + '0';
        else
            binaryToHex[0] = hexLetters[k-10];

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your logic is right? I tried following it with an input of 10 to no avail. there's so many things wrong with this code i think.

Anyway to your question

this statement: binaryToHex[1] = remainder;

or this statement:  binaryToHex[0] = wholeNumber;

assigns an int to binaryToHex[0];

so when you printed it using printf("%c", binaryToHex[1]);

you can change your printf to printf("%i", binaryToHex[1]) which will print out the number. However base on what I see on your code, binaryToHex[1] and [0] for that matter could be assign either a number or a char, so if it was assign a char but you use %i then you will have the same problem. you could instead add the asci number of the integer 0 to your statement by appending it like binaryToHex[1] = remainder + '0'. so if the value of binaryToHex[1] is 7, you will be printing an unprintable ascii character but by adding '0' or 48 to it you will be printing the ascii representation of 55 which is 7, just like you wanted. but i think you should think about rewriting your code instead to avoid these hacks.

anyway i think you should start with your code logic cause i think its flawed, but I could be wrong as I don't have a compiler to test it on.

Comment: I agree there are more then likely many errors, I have never learned C and my teacher has assigned everyone to do a project in it.  Thats why I need as much help as possible. Thanks for the responce